# ¿Cual es la lógica del bucle for?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un sencillo ejercicio en el cual pide que:
Imprima en el DOM una lista de numeros del 1 al 30, incrementandose de 3 en 3.

En el primer ejemplo a `i` le sumo 2 con el operador `+` pero no me da el resultado

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    document.write((i+2) + "<br>");
}
```

Y en el segundo ejemplo le sumo a `i` el siguiente operador `+=` y en esta ocasión si me da lo deseado.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    document.write((i+=2) + "<br>");
}
```

**¿Por que sucede eso si se supone que ambos operadores hacen lo mismo?**

Comment: Pero el segundo código tampoco va del 1 al 30 pues inicia en 2 y termina en 32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El asunto va de este modo:

**Caso 1**

Para el primer escenario la salida va así:

```
i    valorNuevo Resultado
0       0+2         2
1       1+2         3
2       2+2         4
```

Es decir:

- El valor de **`i`** va aumentando de 1 en 1 y a cada valor que se genera en cada una de las vueltas se le va sumando un 2 como puedes observar en la tabl anterior.

**Caso 2**

Dado que indicas que vaya aumentando de 3 en 3 desde el 1 al 30, entonces tal vez el código debe ser así:

```js
    for(let i=3; i<=30; i+=3) {
      console.log(i)
    }
```

Donde:

- Hacemos la suma dentro de la última parte del ciclo for, que es el incremento; donde regularmente hacemos **`variable++`** que es equivalente a sumarle la unidad por cada vuelta al valor actual, entonces por el contrario ahora vamos a aumentarle 3 por cada iteración.
- Dentro del **`for`** solo mandamos a imprimir la varibale que por cada iteración contiene el valor actual que es la **`i`**

Comment: Me queda claro esta explicación ahora entiendo. Muchas gracias
¿Se podría decir que los operadores de asignación son comúnmente usados en los bucles para realizar estas operaciones?

Comment: En su estructura el ciclo for recibe como 3cer elemento el incremento, que puede ser la unidad o cualquier otro número; tanto positivo como negativo dependiendo de lo que busquemos obtener, podemos tener **`variable+=5`** o también **`variable = variable + 5`**

Comment: Entiendo.Me queda muy claro ahora. Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia es que en el primer caso simplemente estás imprimiendo para cada iteración de `i` el valor de la suma de `i+2` (**sin modificar** `i`), mientras que en el segundo caso, además, en cada iteración estás sumando al iterador `i` ese `+2`; es decir, lo estás **modificando**.

Comment: ¿Es como si en el primer caso el +2 fuera estatico
y en el segundo caso el +=2 hace que aparte sume a i ?

Comment: Claro, en el primer caso sólo lees un valor calculado con la expresión `i+2`, mientras que en el segundo caso haces `i = i + 2` (que es lo mismo que `i += 2`). Por lo tanto en el segundo caso, lees el resultado de esa asignación que, además, modifica el flujo del bucle